# Convert JavaScript variable string to JSON using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a string in JavaScript I want to make some kind of `JSON` of key value pair. Here is string

```
 {
    "questionId": null,
    "articleId": null,
    "questionText": "eewrr",
    "pollType": null,
    "selectedOptionIds": [],
    "pollOptionList": [{
        "optionId": 0,
        "questionId": 0,
        "optionText": "werwer",
        "selectedByUser": "N",
        "createdDate": null,
        "modifiedDate": null
    }, {
        "optionId": 0,
        "questionId": 0,
        "optionText": "werwer",
        "selectedByUser": "N",
        "createdDate": null,
        "modifiedDate": null
    }, {
        "optionId": 0,
        "questionId": 0,
        "optionText": "werwer",
        "selectedByUser": "N",
        "createdDate": null,
        "modifiedDate": null
    }, {
        "optionId": 0,
        "questionId": 0,
        "optionText": "werwe",
        "selectedByUser": "N",
        "createdDate": null,
        "modifiedDate": null
    }, {
        "optionId": 0,
        "questionId": 0,
        "optionText": "rwer",
        "selectedByUser": "N",
        "createdDate": null,
        "modifiedDate": null
    }],
    "pollId": 37
}
```

Comment: parse this via JSON.parse() you will get object

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JSON.parse()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) please find below snippet for more information

```js
var json = JSON.parse('{"questionId":null,"articleId":null,"questionText":"eewrr","pollType":null,"selectedOptionIds":[],"pollOptionList":[{"optionId":0,"questionId":0,"optionText":"werwer","selectedByUser":"N","createdDate":null,"modifiedDate":null},{"optionId":0,"questionId":0,"optionText":"werwer","selectedByUser":"N","createdDate":null,"modifiedDate":null},{"optionId":0,"questionId":0,"optionText":"werwer","selectedByUser":"N","createdDate":null,"modifiedDate":null},{"optionId":0,"questionId":0,"optionText":"werwe","selectedByUser":"N","createdDate":null,"modifiedDate":null},{"optionId":0,"questionId":0,"optionText":"rwer","selectedByUser":"N","createdDate":null,"modifiedDate":null}],"pollId":37}') 
console.log(json);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

for that purpose use

```
   JSON.parse()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var your_str = '{"questionId":null,"articleId":null,"questionText":"eewrr","pollType":null,"selectedOptionIds":[],"pollOptionList":[{"optionId":0,"questionId":0,"optionText":"werwer","selectedByUser":"N","createdDate":null,"modifiedDate":null},{"optionId":0,"questionId":0,"optionText":"werwer","selectedByUser":"N","createdDate":null,"modifiedDate":null},{"optionId":0,"questionId":0,"optionText":"werwer","selectedByUser":"N","createdDate":null,"modifiedDate":null},{"optionId":0,"questionId":0,"optionText":"werwe","selectedByUser":"N","createdDate":null,"modifiedDate":null},{"optionId":0,"questionId":0,"optionText":"rwer","selectedByUser":"N","createdDate":null,"modifiedDate":null}],"pollId":37}';
var obj = JSON.parse(your_str);
alert(obj);
//or
console.log(obj);
```

Here your_str is your json string.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to parse it as an JSON Object
So it's going to be:

```
JSON.parse('{"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": {"4": 4, "5": {"6": 6}}}', (key, value));
```

In your case it will be:

```
JSON.parse('{"questionId":null,"articleId":null,"questionText":"eewrr","pollType":null,"selectedOptionIds":[],"pollOptionList":[{"optionId":0,"questionId":0,"optionText":"werwer","selectedByUser":"N","createdDate":null,"modifiedDate":null},{"optionId":0,"questionId":0,"optionText":"werwer","selectedByUser":"N","createdDate":null,"modifiedDate":null},{"optionId":0,"questionId":0,"optionText":"werwer","selectedByUser":"N","createdDate":null,"modifiedDate":null},{"optionId":0,"questionId":0,"optionText":"werwe","selectedByUser":"N","createdDate":null,"modifiedDate":null},{"optionId":0,"questionId":0,"optionText":"rwer","selectedByUser":"N","createdDate":null,"modifiedDate":null}],"pollId":37}', key, value));
```

I hope I have provided you with enough information

Answer (score 0):

use `JSON.parse()` for converting string to json 
and `JSON.stringify()` for converting json to string